# ShareKit customize SHKSharer appearance

Tags: sharekit

Can i, and if i can how to customize appearance of SHKSharer?
I need to change it size because it appears for portrait orientation, and background color, navBar etc.

screenshot from my app 
http://i.piccy.info/i9/d255df2cd7ec8611bd8888a885f1efb4/1416750336/206827/824231/Snymok_ekrana_2014_11_23_v_15_43_21.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From DefaultSHKConfigurator.m:

```
///You can override methods from Configuration section (see SHKFormController.h) to use your own cell subclasses.
- (Class)SHKFormControllerSubclass {
    return NSClassFromString(@"SHKFormController");
}
```

So subclass SHKFormController and override this method in your configurator to let ShareKit use your subclass.

Comment: Don't you know how can i change view size?